How to sum in a column from the max value upwards until the value is not descending?
How to sum in a column from the max value upwards until the value is not descending?
Here is the example:



A
15




1



2



3



1



2



3



4







5



1



2



3



4



5




I want a cell to calculate the sum value from the max value in a column, sum them upwards, until the number is no longer descending. Sometimes there will be an empty cell(with formulas in it), and of course we need to skip that and keep going upward until the value is not descending. In the future data, 6, or 7(new max value) might happen and there might be empty cell with formulas in the middle of the descending value.
What formula could I use?
Again, this formula is only for a single cell, like in the example, a single cell showing "15".
Thank you so much for your reply!

It is difficult to know what you want. Please [edit] your question to include an example of the expected result based on your current data.

Assigns a unique number to each ascending group & then filters the group which has the max value to sum
=let(x,filter(A:A,A:A<>""),y,scan(1,sequence(rows(x)),lambda(a,c,iferror(if(index(x,c)>=index(x,c-1),a,a+1),a))),
            sum(filter(x,y=xlookup(max(x),x,y))))

